# IBMMQDotnetClient is compatible with IBMMQ 7.5?

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I am using that very useful project as reference:

[Github](https://github.com/micheleissa/IBMMQResilientClient), thanks to micheleissa.

Considering my situation of legacy IBMMQ version (7.5), which also does not use a password, as allowed only for internal connections with only username, is that possible to use that project with IBMMQDotnetClient 9.2.2 from Nuget.

I tried to add this line, and have no success

```
            _connectionOptions = new Hashtable()
            {
                { MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
                { MQC.APPNAME_PROPERTY, _queueOptions.AppName },
                { MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, _queueOptions.Channel },
                { MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR },
                { MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, string.Join(",", _queueOptions.MqHostOptionsList.Select(opt => $"{opt.HostName}({opt.Port})"))},
                { MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, $"{_queueOptions.Username}"},
                { MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, false}
                //{ MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, $"{_queueOptions.Password}" }
            };
```

But I have only these parameters:

- queueManager:TESTMANAGER
- channel:TESTCHANNEL
- connName:test.info.net
- port: 1416
- name:TEST.INFO
- user:svc_test

And to be honest, I think that user is not even necessary.
I tried this code using docker IBMMQ 9.2, using all parameters and it is working.

MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED : 2035

Comment: Please add the error message from your queue manager AMQERR01.LOG to show what the security failure was.

Comment: Show your code.   If you don't specified a username and password it will only send across the use you are running under.

Comment: @MoragHughson I will try to get it when reach the infra team.

Comment: @JoshMc I did some changes, if possible to check it again if it helps anything.

Comment: IBM MQ 7.5 qmgrs will ignore the userid.  What user does your 9.2.2 application run as?  Try running it as the user you are trying to set.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly my company made a mess, but I had to remove

```
{ MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, $"{_queueOptions.Username}"},
```

because in that case, ibmmq was using the machine user automatically, so then add this account to the system.

Comment: This usually means your queue manager is not providing authentication of the connection.   You could define any trusted user local and connect to the queue manager with that level of authority.  Did your application behave differently with and without the `MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY` set, I think it would act the same, it would send the user the app runs as and ignore the property.